# Какие действуют ограничения для телеграм-ботов?

Tags: telegram-bot

Искал в этих ваших интернетах статьи и видео про ограничения для ботов в телеграм. Нашел одну занятную статью на сайте uni**nder.com (не реклама).

Вопрос такой, с какими ограничениями сталкивались вы при написании бота? Этот вопос имеет под собой почву, а было все так:

Я имея базу данных с пользователями, решил сделать массовую рассылку, которую бы запускал Cron на серваке хостинга. Простой цикл берет группу пользователей и каждому по очереди пишет сообщение, не спам.

Проблема была тогда, когда я в один прекрасный момент понял, что мой бот просто перестал работать, я не получил уведомлений от телеги, бот не был ограничен в функионале, не получил меток (типа scam и тд) а тупо умер.

Вот и решил узанть пользовательски опыт, кто знает, чего нельзя делть)

Буду рад адекватным комментариям, а если кто то влепит минус путь имеет совесть обосновать свой поступок.

Comment: Что значит "умер"?

Comment: @oleksandrigo код не менялся, хук стоит, но бот перестал реагировать на входящий пост-запрос от php://input. Я в своих ботах всегда делаю отладку через запись файл (беру php://input, декодирую в JSON, помещаю все это в переменную $event и записываю в текстовый файл через file_put_content(print_r) (псевдокод) Но с недавних пор в $event вегда исключчительно пустая строка

Answer (score -1):

Если слишком часто отправлять сообщения, то вы получите HTTP-ошибку [429 Too Many Requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/429). Об этом написано в документации Telegram Bot API, а также в [FAQ](https://core.telegram.org/bots/faq#my-bot-is-hitting-limits-how-do-i-avoid-this) есть возможные способы решения этой проблемы:

> Если вы отправляете массовые уведомления многим пользователям, API не будет позволять отправлять более 30 сообщений в секунду (или где-то так). Рассмотрите возможность распределить уведомления пользователям на большой интервал 8—12 часов для лучших результатов.

Проверте серверные логи на наличие 429-х ошибок.

Comment: Проверял, но не обнорожил( в итогде принял решение после каждой отправки взывать ```sleep(5);```  Но вопрос еще есть,почему тот бот до сих пор не реагиhetn ни на что? Уже прошла почти неделя. Даже Админ моего хостинга пытася найти конфликтующий код и просматиривал логи. Но мы ни к чему не пришли. Вот что обидно

Comment: После того, как вы начинаете получать 429 ошибку, должно пройти какое-то время, чтобы бот снова заработал. В этом и смысл этой ошибки, ограничить отправку большого количества сообщений в секунду.

Comment: Ваш вопрос был "Какие действуют ограничения для телеграм-ботов?" и "С какими ограничениями сталкивались вы при написании бота?". Если я ответил на него, вы можете зачитать его как правильный. То, что вы сейчас спрашиваете -- это уже другой вопрос, вы можете задать новый вопрос нажав "Задать вопрос" вверху страницы.

Comment: ну тут смотря как ограничиват :) Можно ограничить (тупо не совершать отправку) а можно откладывать отправку, с чем впринципе телега думаю играть не будет)